Python telegram bot with Aiogram
I want to make a back button while creating telegram bot. I need to make this button in ReplyKeyboardButton, but back button works for all functions and handlers. For example, there are two main buttons: Users and Lessons. In Users there are also three buttons: "Edit Users" and "Show Users" and "Back". If I press the button back it needs to return to main buttons. "Users" and "Lessons". If I press the button "Lessons" there are also three buttons: "Python" "Java" and "Back". And if I press the button "Back" it needs to return to main buttons. This means, the button "Back" has to work accordingly to sets of buttons
I have no idea with it

Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add all the relevant code.
